# Unable to use Checkbox in an Access form as ,it says "This Recordset is not Updatable"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have created a local temporary table in Access Frontend. I have my backend in SQL Server. Now I created the table so that it can be used in a form. This is an SMS form. So this table consists of:

```
[ID] - AutoNumber and PK
[CNR]
[RelationID]
[FullName] 
[PhoneNumber]
[Check] (Checkbox)
```

Now I have a main menu form with an SMS button on it. When the user clicks the SMS button a form opens up with a subform that is created from the temporary local table. This table is populated using the Select query

```
SQLstr = "INSERT INTO [_TempPhone_tbl]([CNR],[FullName],[PhoneNumber],[RelationID])SELECT [1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].PCNR, [1-02_ClientRelations_tbl].[FirstName]+' '+[1-02_ClientRelations_tbl].[Surname] AS RelationName,[1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].PhoneNumber,[1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].RelationID " _
& " FROM [1-02_ClientRelations_tbl] " _
& " INNER JOIN [1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw] ON [1-02_ClientRelations_tbl].RelationID = [1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].RelationID " _
& " Where [1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].PCNR = " & Me.CNR & " AND [1-04_RelationsPhoneTBT_vw].Active = True "
```

The form opens up like this

[image]

Now, whenever I try to select a record by pressing the checkbox it shows the record set is not updatable. I don't understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

Long time and known access issue.

On the sql server side, make sure the bit field (true/false) can NOT be and allow nulls. And ALSO make sure the default is set = 0

eg this:

So, say we have a true/false (bit) field in sql server called Active.

So,  you have to from SSMS first do this:

```
UPDATE tblHotelsA SET Active = 0 WHERE Active is null
```

Then open up the sql table, and check for two VERY important issues:

Make sure the defult for that true/false column has a default of 0 (false), AND ALSO ensure that the column does not allow nulls.

So, our column name is "Active", so this:

[image]

So, in above, we un-check "allow nulls".

and then we set the default to 0, so now this:

[image]

Ok so now you should re-link your table.

At this point, it should work.

Now, is that temp table a local access table, or is it a sql server table?

And double/tripe check that your form is based on that access local table if it is a local table.

So, a local access table should never have an issue. However, if the table in question is a sql server table, and your so called temp table is a linked sql server table, then you MUST set the "bit" field in sql server as per above.

so, not allow nulls, and set default = 0 for any sql server table you want  to link to AND ALSO want to be able to edit as a linked table.

As noted, if this is a local access table in your access front end, then of course it will work fine, but for linked tables, bit fields MUST have default = 0, and allow nulls check box must be un-checked.

Comment: D.Kallal Thank you a lot for your reply and also for letting me know what changes to do if the table is in SQL and linked to access.  Actually, in my case,  the table is in Access Frontend and is a local table. I don't understand why it is encountering this error as it is just the data that is populated and no query is present.

Comment: double check the form - make sure the data source is not a query, but is based directly on that local table. And try opening the table after being populated with data directly as a table from Access (not the form), and see if you can edit it that way.

Comment: D.Kallal I'm able to edit the data in the table after the table is populated. But still unable to edit in the form.

Comment: So that is a sub form (or sub datasheet). Open that form directly (not as sub form). Does it then work? Since this is a local table, then we are missing a elephant in the room here - we just are. try building a continues form (multiple items) -- try that form, does it work? If yes, then drop in that new sub form to your above main form - try that.

Comment: D.Kallal I opened the form directly and wasn't able to edit it as well. I tried it as a continuous form as well but didn't work.

Comment: Well, if this is a local table, and you can open and edit that table to edit? Then what you seeing makes ZERO sense. Just use the wizard to create a form against that table. Can you edit that? So, use the wizard to create a new form - multiple items, or even a data sheet form. Can you edit with that form? Ok, now drop this form into your existing form you have above (I assume this form is being used as a sub form???). I mean, at this point in time, this has ZERO to do with sql server, since we are talking about a local non linked table. So question is about a form and local table then, right?

Comment: D.Kallal I was able to fix it by Re-creating the temporal table. I didn't understand why it didn't work earlier. Thanks a million for your help. :)